# Plot multiple violin plots where data each datapoint may belong to multiple categories in matplotlib

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I'mlooking to plot multiple violin plots on the same set of axes. I have a datagrams where each entry may belong to one or more categories, and I'd like to plot a violin plot of some other variable for each category.

Example data:

| Score | Cat A | Cat B | Cat C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 6 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 7 | 1 | 0 | 1 |

And for this data I would like to plot a violin plot of the score for each of the three categories

I have attempted plotting a subplot for each category, but this results in a large number of separate graphs when ideally everything would be on the same axes

Comment: If you'd [add](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75099287/edit) your attempted test code and the corresponding plot, your post would be easier to understand, and easier to answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can create multiple dataframe for each category and then violin plot each:

```py
categories = ["Cat A", "Cat B", "Cat C"]
dataframes = [df[df[cat] == 1] for cat in categories]
```

Full example:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 100

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Score": np.random.randn(N),
        "Cat A": np.random.randint(low=0, high=2, size=N),
        "Cat B": np.random.randint(low=0, high=2, size=N),
        "Cat C": np.random.randint(low=0, high=2, size=N),
    }
)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

categories = ["Cat A", "Cat B", "Cat C"]
ticks = np.arange(1, len(categories) + 1)

ax.violinplot([df[df[cat] == 1]["Score"] for cat in categories], positions=ticks)

ax.set_xticks(ticks=ticks, labels=categories)
ax.set_xticklabels(categories)

plt.show()
```

[image: violin plots]